# transition hoooks only called when transition element is root element in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've noticed that transition hooks only get fired when the `<transition>` element is the root element in my component template. Is this by design? Am I missing something?

in my `App.vue` I have this template:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="checked">
<label for="checkbox">{{ checked }}</label>
<example v-if = "checked"></example>
```

My component `example.vue`:

```
<template lang="html">

  <section class="example">
     <transition
        v-on:enter = "enter"
        v-on:leave = "leave">
        <div class = "transition-example"></div>
    </transition>
  </section>

</template>

<script lang="js">
  export default  {
    name: 'example',
    props: [],
    mounted() {

    },
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    methods: {
      enter: function (el, done) {
        console.log("enter")
        done()
      },
      leave: function(el, done) {
        console.log("leave")
        done()
      }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped >

</style>
```

In this current exmaple the `enter` and `leave` hooks are never executed when toggling the checkbox.

If I would update the template of `example.vue` to make sure the `<transitions>` element is the root element (as shown below) the `enter` and `leave` hooks are called.

```
<template lang="html">

  <transition
    v-on:enter = "enter"
    v-on:leave = "leave">
    <div class = "transition-example"></div>
  </transition>


</template>
```

I'd like to have more flexibility in where I put my `<transition>` element or have multiple `transition` element in a component, which all have their own hooks.

I'm assuming I am overlooking something that prevents me from doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've noticed that transition hooks only get fired when the  element is the root element in my component template. Is this by design? Am I missing something?

It's because of this line `<example v-if="checked"></example>`. `v-if` is applied to real root element of component so when transition is in root, `v-if` applied to `div` inside transition and it works fine, but in your first case `v-if` applied to `section` which is not under transition. So to  make transition work you should provide `v-if` in element wrapped with `transition` tag, you can pass `checked` as prop to indicate visibility:

App.vue

```
...
<example :visible="checked"></example>
...
```

Example.vue

```
<template lang="html">
  <section class="example">
     <transition
        v-on:enter = "enter"
        v-on:leave = "leave">
        <div v-if="visible" class="transition-example"></div>
    </transition>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! This would indeed solve the issue specific to `v-if`. Any chance you know how I could handle this if don't have a `v-if` and would like to get the `enter` event fired on page load?

Comment: @svdwoude add `appear` directive to `transition` tag and related hooks. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render